# Increase volume of alarm in countdown timer?

Tags: iphone

iPhone's "Clock App" has a countdown timer which sounds an alarm when the countdown is down.

Is there a way to make the alarm significantly louder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three avenues to this:

1. get a soft toothbrush and make sure the speaker grill is clean and free of debris
2. position the phone so the speaker echoes/reverberates from a hard reflective surface that channels the sound to your ears.
3. choose custom alarm tones that are [audio compressed and recorded "hot"](http://sound.westhost.com/compression.htm) and perhaps alternate loud/soft as your brain will hear the changes as more relevant than a flat loud monotone

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no (official) way to increase the volume above the configured maximum. Some of the default sounds provided are quieter then others, you might consider using the "Alarm" sound, or set two alarms minutes apart.

If this still doesn't work you might consider a jailbreak application. Volume Booster 4 seems to be the current best.

Comment: what do you mean the "Alarm" sound?